# JDialog keeps reopening

Tags: java, dialog, jdialog

So I have a JDialog box that opens whenever you want to make something new in the program I'm making. The first time you open it, it works fine when you close it. But the second time, when you close it, it reopens and you have to close it for a second time. If you were to open it for a third time, you would have to close it three times, and you can see where I'm getting at. I'm assuming it's how I am showing it, and where I am setting it visible and not visible so those are the segments of code I will present, but if you need anything else just ask. The JDialog box itself is a separate class by the way. Thanks in advance.

**First Creating the Dialog**

`private NewPlatformDialog npd = new NewPlatformDialog(frame, "New Platform", this);`

**Opening it**

```
else if(source == mouseNewPlatform || source == newPlatform) {
    npd.setVisible(true);
}
```

**Places where I close it (first one in constructor)**

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
pack();
setVisible(false);
```

**Button to close it**

`if(source == cancel) setVisible(false);`

**Apply Button**

```
`
else if(source == add) {
    if(platformSelector.getSelectedIndex() == 0) {
        int x = 0, y = 0, w = 0, h = 0;
        if(xField != null) x = Integer.parseInt(xField.getText());
        if(yField != null) y = Integer.parseInt(yField.getText());
        if(widthField != null) w = Integer.parseInt(widthField.getText());
        if(heightField != null) h = Integer.parseInt(heightField.getText());

        le.platforms.add(new DragablePlatform(x, y, w, h, Platform.NORMAL));
        le.repaint();

        resetFields();
        setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

While I don't think I'm doing anything wrong, I could be mistaken, so again thanks in advance for any help.

**DragablePlatform Class**

```
package resources;

public class DragablePlatform extends Platform {
public DragablePlatform(int x, int y, int w, int h, int type) {
    super(x, y, w, h, type);
}
public DragablePlatform(int x, int y, int w, int h, int type, int horizVerti, int max) {
    super(x, y, w, h, type, horizVerti, max);
}
}
```

Comment: My Crystall Ball (tm) tells me that `DragablePlatform` registers event listeners too that open the additional dialogs.

Comment: @ThomasKläger well that makes no sense, beause my `DragablePlatform` class never references the `NewPlatformDialog` class.

Comment: Fact is: a dialog is visible or not. You cannot nest calls to `dialog.setVisible(true);`, so it must be either consecutive calls to show and hide the same dialog several times, or it must be several identical dialogs overlapping each other. Which one depends upon your code. So if you want more than wild guesses then please include more code. It could also be a problem if `DragablePlatform`inherits from your current class, so please include the essential parts of this class too (at least class definition with extends and implements and constructor)

Comment: @ThomasKläger I added the `DragablePlatform` class in its entirety because it is a very small class. And as for the 2 suggestions you made, neither make sense. For the first one, consecutive calls would make sense, but why would it always coincide with the times I opened the dialog. The second one doesn't make sense, because I store the dialog in a variable and only define the variable once, so it shouldn't be making multile

Comment: @ThomasKläger nevermind, I was able to finally narrow down the problem. The way I have it, is that one of  the ways you can open the `JDialog` is through a submenu when you right click. However, I kept reading the `JMenuItem`s when you right click, which explains what was happening, so it was my own stupid fault. Thanks for trying to help, but turns out you can't help stupidity.

Comment: No problem - I've done those stupid mistakes too